# How can I use openssl RSA public key to decrypt with out read the pem file

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, pem

I send a string of the client's public key from a pem file and want to use this string to do decryption on server without writing the string into another pem file. How can I do it?

read key code:

```
if ( (my_public_key = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, NULL, My_PWD, NULL)) == NULL) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

do decrypt code:

```
rsa_len = RSA_size(target_public_key);
p_de = (unsigned char*)malloc(rsa_len+1);
memset(p_de, 0, rsa_len+1);
if (RSA_public_decrypt(rsa_len, (unsigned char*)from_hex,p_de , target_public_key, RSA_NO_PADDING) <0) {
    perror("can't decrypt data!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I've tagged this as [tag:c], please correct the language if I'm mistaken.

Comment: While the routine is effectively called `RSA_public_decrypt`, what you're really doing with the public key is verifying the signature, not decrypting (by definition of encryption/decryption).